# memory usage in Chrome using javascript (window.performance.memory)

Tags: performance, google-chrome, memory

I was expecting that `window.performance.memory` - when called regularly with a `setTimeout` function - would display an updated amount of used memory. However, values seem to never change. Is there something specific that I should do in order to get updated values?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the updates in real time you need to start chrome with this flag: "--enable-precise-memory-info".